# onServiceConnected is not called on Android 5.1.1 using InAppBillingService

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am using the code below to bind the InAppBillingService. It is working like a charm on Android 4.3 (Samsung Galaxy S3). However when I run the app on a Android 5.1.1(Sony Xperia Z1) device, `onServiceConnected` just not called without giving an error or warning on logcat.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    mService = null;
}
```

Btw, gradle configuration is below:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 13
    versionName "0.1.13"
    applicationId "com.kepraes.wtl"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
```

PS: I am not using `IAB` library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I factory resetted the device and updated all Google apps. The problem is just gone for good. I suspect "Lucky Patcher" app screwed up something behind, and factory resetting just fixed that.